# Can I return a page in flask and then run a python function?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

Currently, I have a python function running, and then have a flask redirect to my page. Is there a way to do the redirect first and then have my python function run? I am using mysql connector so I am not sure of a way to pass that through jQuery or Ajax.

```
@ app.route('/page', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page():
    if request.method == "POST":
    
        function_a(sql)
        return redirect('/page2')
```

I would like the code to run the redirect, then function_a. Any way to do this?

Comment: If you want to  redirect to some other route, why don't you put the rest of the logic there.

Comment: Did you even try it?  Of course you can call `redirect` first and do whatever you want after.  None of that has anything to do with jQuery or Ajax.  Once you do the `redirect`, the response will be sent to the client, and whatever you do after is local to the server.